# Upgrading .netcore 6 to from Core 3.1 throwing error System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json' Version=7.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

Migrated the .netcore 3.1 to .net6 and updated the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json from 3.1.6 to 7.0.0

Have a Powershell task in release pipeline which basically run this C# code and tries to load the appsetting json file.

Getting exception

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or load a specific
> file. (0x80131621)

Expecting to resolve this exception.

Comment: Do you have a step to restore nuget packages in your release pipeline ? If not try adding one, as `System.Text.Json` is a direct dependency of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` (as can be seen on nuget.org). If all else fails, try manually adding the `System.Text.Json` nuget package.

Comment: Did you download Core 6?  See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download?force_isolation=true

Comment: Manually adding the System.Text.Json nuget still getting the same error

Comment: I have not downloaded Core 6 sdk. Do I have to down load the sdk?

Comment: This issue may be due to a mismatch between the version of the System.Text.Json assembly that your application is referencing and the version that is installed on the machine where the application is running.